# Derivative of a sum

Tags: derivatives, summation

$$L(a,b) = {\sum_{i=1}^n (y^i - (ax^i +b)^2)^2})$$
$$\frac{dL}{da} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(y^i-y^-)*(x^i-x^-))}{var(x)}$$

How can I canclulate the $\frac{dL}{da}$?

$$2(y^i - (ax^i +b))^2)* \frac{d(y^i - (ax^i +b)^2)}{da} = $$

Comment: you should show your thought process and work of the problem

Comment: May I echo Eric's thoughts above. Also, you probably mean to find $\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}$? Are you familiar with the sum rule?

Comment: You are right. In fact, I am not used to the derivative of sums. Yes I mean the derivative of L based on a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L(a,b) = {\sum_{i=1}^n (y^i - (ax^i +b)^2)^2}$$

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial a} &= \sum_{i=1}^n 2(y^i-(ax^i+b)^2)\frac{\partial (y^i-(ax^i+b)^2)}{\partial a} \\
&= -2\sum_{i=1}^n (y^i-(ax^i+b)^2)\frac{\partial ((ax^i+b)^2)}{\partial a} \\
&=-4\sum_{i=1}^n (y^i-(ax^i+b)^2)(ax^i+b)x^i \\
\end{align}

where in the first line I have used the fact that differentiation is linear and I have repeatedly used chain rule.

Comment: chain rule, $\frac{\partial v^2}{\partial a} = 2v\frac{\partial v}{\partial a}$